# ImportError when importing Flask WTF forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

I can't see where I'm going wrong. I have the latest WTF forms installed but I still get this error.

Method:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import PasswordField, validators, fields
from wtforms.fields import TextField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Email, EqualTo
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 67, in __call__
self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/logging/__init__.py", line 1269, in exception
self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/logging/__init__.py", line 1262, in error
self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/logging/__init__.py", line 1368, in _log
self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/logging/__init__.py", line 1377, in handle
if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.3/logflask_wtf
wtformsging/__init__.py", line 687, in filter
for f in self.filters:
 File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 59, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
 File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 73, in import_error_application
raise e
 File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 82, in <module>
application = load_wsgi_application()
 File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 78, in load_wsgi_application
return __import__(os.environ['WSGI_MODULE'], globals(), locals(),     ['application']).application
 File "/var/www/rcham_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
from addressbook.app import app as application
 File "/home/rcham/mysite/addressbook/app.py", line 4, in <module>
from addressbook.forms import LoginForm, ContactsForm
 File "/home/rcham/mysite/addressbook/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf
```

```
ls /home/rcham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask

    __init__.py blueprints.py debughelpers.py globals.pyc logging.pyc signals.pyc
    views.py __init__.pyc blueprints.pyc debughelpers.pyc helpers.py module.py 
    templating.py views.pyc _compat.py config.py ext helpers.pyc module.pyc 
    templating.pyc wrappers.py _compat.pyc config.pyc exthook.py json.py 
    sessions.py testing.py wrappers.pyc app.py ctx.py exthook.pyc json.pyc 
    sessions.pyc testing.pyc app.pyc ctx.pyc globals.py logging.py signals.py 
    testsuite


ls /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/ | grep wtf

   flask_wtf
   wtforms
```

Comment: How did you installed flask-wtf? Your code is fine, it is probably an environment issue.

Comment: Could you post `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/flask` and `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/ | grep wtf`?

Comment: ls /home/rcham/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask
__init__.py blueprints.py debughelpers.py globals.pyc logging.pyc signals.pyc views.py
__init__.pyc blueprints.pyc debughelpers.pyc helpers.py module.py templating.py views.pyc
_compat.py config.py ext helpers.pyc module.pyc templating.pyc wrappers.py
_compat.pyc config.pyc exthook.py json.py sessions.py testing.py wrappers.pyc
app.py ctx.py exthook.pyc json.pyc sessions.pyc testing.pyc
app.pyc ctx.pyc globals.py logging.py signals.py testsuite

Comment: Its working now, you are right they were installed in the wrong place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official quickstart](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html), `flask.ext.wtf` should be `flask_wtf`.

So you have to import it as:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```

At least I have, I installed from pip.

Comment: If you are using a script to run your code (run.py for example), check you are running the right python version with : "which python" or "which python3".  Make sure you run this inside your virtualenv if you are using one.

Answer (score 5):

Please use

```
from flask_wtf import Form

from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField,IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import Required
```

This has been changed since v0.8

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you installed only `wtforms`, not `Flask-WTF` extension.

To install `Flask-WTF`: `pip install flask-wtf`

Comment: I've installed Flask-WTF

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wtf.validators required changed from using the Required() method to DataRequired() method. So change:

`from wtforms.validators import Required, Email, EqualTo`

to:

`from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo`

and modify all references to the Required() method to DataRequired.

It appears Required method is Depreciated as of WTForms 3.0
https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/validators/